# Copy a photo and metadata selected using UIImagePicker to a new photo with modified Exif metadata

Tags: ios, swift, metadata

I would like to be able to select a photo from the Photos library using UIImagePicker and copy all  the image (with modified Exif metadata) to a new photo which I save in Photos. If I use UIActivityViewController to choose the save option (from copy/save/assign to contact/print/add to shared album/save to file),  the input image metadata is not transferred when I create a new UIimage from the loaded image data with the modified metadata. How can get the image with modified metadata attached to the saved photo?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: How did you plan to modify the metadata?

Comment: Add text in  Exif UserComment field. The field should be added if not present

Answer (score 2):

Eventually found out how to do this. The code executed after the image picker is below. The important thing is to create the source from which the metadata is extracted from a URL, not from data from image.jpegData. The jpegData option only includes metadata essential to JPEG operation

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

     let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

    if let image = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage {

        let url  = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL.rawValue]
       
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as! CFURL, nil)
      
        let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source!,0,nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
        var metadataAsMutable = metadata
        //let ImagePropertyExifDictionary = kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary
        
        guard var exif = metadataAsMutable![kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] as? [String:Any] else {return}
        if((exif[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment as String] == nil))
        {
        exif[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment as String] = "Test User Comment"
        }
        metadataAsMutable![kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] = exif as CFDictionary
        
       ImagePickerView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        let image2 = image.imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 300,right: 0))
        let data1 = image2!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        newData = addImageProperties(imageData: data1!, properties: metadataAsMutable! as CFDictionary)
        image3 = UIImage(data:newData)!
        
        ImagePickerView.image = image3

        captionButton.isEnabled = true; saveButton.isEnabled = true;
        
    }else {
        print("Error")
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func addImageProperties(imageData: Data, properties: NSMutableDictionary) -> Data? {
  
 if let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil) {
  if let uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source) {
      let destinationData = NSMutableData()
      if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(destinationData, uti, 1, nil) {
      CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, properties)
      if CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) == false {
      return nil
    }                    
    return destinationData as Data
  }
}
```

}
return nil
}

After obtaining newData, the save button IBAction is

```
@IBAction func shareAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.saveImageDataAsImage(newData)
 }
```

and the function to save the image in the same album as the selected image is

```
 func saveImageDataAsImage(_ data: Data) {
    var newImageIdentifier: String!

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges{
        //if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            let assetRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
            assetRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: data, options: nil)
            newImageIdentifier = assetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!.localIdentifier
//            } else {
//                // Fallback on earlier versions
//            }
    } completionHandler: { (success, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if success, let newAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [newImageIdentifier], options: nil).firstObject {
                // ...
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        })

    }
}
```